# Selecting and adding values accorss multiple databases

Tags: mysql

-- Ramble --

I'm just running through some hypothetical setups in my head for a possible project that I may try to do whenever I have some free time. Basically I was just going to create a simple dynamic website where users can register and host their own website that's generated in PHP.  I've done this before however now that I've learned quite a bit about OOP I'd like to try it again without the source being a mess.

-- End ramble --

Basically, what I'm wanting to know is how to select values across multiple databases and perform logic with them. For example, lets say I have 3 databases laid out like so:

```
website_1
   |_ Users
website_2
   |_Users
website_3
   |_Users
```

The `Users` table would consist of two columns for this example. (ID, Points), both of which are INT(11) NOT NULL values.

The query should return the name of the database, the amount of users, and the sum of the users points. For example:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Database  | user_count | total_points |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Website_1 |          3 |         2170 |
| Website_2 |          7 |         4020 |
| Website_3 |          2 |         1480 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

After some research I've found that the query function "DB_NAME()" should return the name of the database, however any attempt to execute it has given me the following error:

> <s>FUNCTION website_1.DB_NAME does not exist</s>

EDIT: DB_NAME() is for SQL SERVER :: DATABASE() returns respected results in MySQL.

And while I know how to use `SELECT COUNT(ID)` and `SELECT SUM(Points)`I'm not sure how to add the values from multiple databases.  I'm a total loss of ideas here.  The end result of the query I have in mind should look like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Database  | user_count | total_points |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Website_1 |          3 |         2170 |
| Website_2 |          7 |         4020 |
| Website_3 |          2 |         1480 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| Totals    |         12 |         7670 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't try to do this in pure SQL. I think the best approach would be to select the databases from the server in a PHP code (`SHOW DATABASES;`) then collect the databases you need to query and exec the following in a loop:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  "'.$database.'", COUNT(ID), SUM(Points) FROM '.$database.'.USERS;'
```

Print the output to a table (meanwhile you can also sum it) then print the totals.

If you wish to cache it in a table, you can create a table for it, TRUNCATE it before the loop then INSERT the results into it (`INSERT SELECT..`) then you can select the results from it. Then you can add some cronjob or something that in every X minutes will refresh that table. But I think these queries isn't so slow that need to be cached. (If you don't have more thousands databases).

Comment: Even if it is slow, it wouldn't matter. These queries would only ever be executed when I wanted to manually view statistics. This is a great idea and answers the question at hand. (However not in a single query, but that may not even be possible).